# How to "import" test doubles

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I have an existing EmberJS code base onto which I want to introduce some unit tests but I need to mock out some included files. In the example below, how can I inject the HelperClass into the unit tests subject. At the moment the subject can't instantiate because the actual HelperClass pulls in a ton of stuff.

Thanks
Rob

app/models/my-model.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import HelperClass from '../../utils/helper-class';
let model = DS.Model.extend({
    Title: DS.attr('string'),
});
HelperClass.something({ model: model });
export default model;
```

tests/unit/models/my-model-test.js

```
import { moduleForModel, test } from 'ember-qunit';
moduleForModel('my-model', 'Unit | Model | my model', {
    // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
    needs: [],
});
test('it exists', function(assert) {

    // This throws an error !!!!
    var model = this.subject();
    assert.ok(!!model);
});
```

Comment: This is just a pure guess by have you tried injecting your `helper-class` via needs: `needs: ['utils:helper-class'],// or some modification?`.
I am not sure if tests are able of injecting utils as they are able to inject services for example.

Comment: That's the sort of thing I was trying but I get "attemping to register an unkown factory". So I'm trying to figure out how to give it one...... not ok 1 PhantomJS 2.1 - Unit | Model | my model: it exists
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        message: >
            Promise rejected before it exists: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `utils:helper-class`

Comment: Reading on [Ember-cli#naming-conventions](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#naming-conventions)
_"All modules in the app directory can be loaded by the resolver but  typically classes such as mixins and utils should be loaded manually with  an import statement."_
which probably applies to testing, too. Using static import statement woould work? Btw, could you tell us bit more why you need to call
`HelperClass.something({ model: model });`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Pavol Thanks, I'll take a look at that. The class already exists, I'm just trying to wrap some tests around it before making any modifications.